# Polymorphism misunderstanding / redefined virtual function not working

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I think I should start by simplifying my class structure so I can better explain my problem, which I suspect might just be a misunderstanding of the use of virtual.

I have:

```
class Controller{
..
    virtual void InitialiseController(){ //std::cout confirms this is running }
..
}

class AIController : public Controller{
..
    virtual void InitialiseController(){ //some logic here }
..
}
class ComController : public AIController{
..
    virtual void InitialiseController(){ //actually the same logic as parent }
..
}
```

My object, Snake, has a pointer to a Controller `(Controller* _controller)`. When I call the `snake.initialise(..)` method I pass it a new ComController object which then sets snakes _controller equal to the new ComController. I know that that process works successfully.

But when I then call `_controller.InitialiseController();` my debugger shows the program steps into the base class Controller's blank implementation of InitialiseContoller.

I know I've probably oversimplified and you might not be able to help, but I think perhaps it's something I'm not understanding about the whole concept, a logic error, rather than a typed error and would like to check.

**Additional code:**

```
_player2->Initialise(_gameProperties, &_fruitManager, new ComController(_player2), _player1);
```

stepping in ..

```
void Snake::Initialise(
   GamePropertiesManager* gpm, FruitManager* fm, Controller* control, Snake* opposingSnake)
{
   _game = gpm;
   _fruitManager = fm;
   _controller = control;
   _opposition = opposingSnake;

   if(_controller){

           ///Bunch of stuff in here runs just fine


      // This primarily serves to ensure that a ComControllers timer is started, but other controllers might wish to override initialise later
      _controller->IntialiseController();

   }

}
```

Comment: Are you pretty sure that the base class function is getting called? Did you check by putting some output message in some functions? The debugger sometimes mess up things in the optimized build.

Comment: If `_controller` is a pointer to `Controller`, then you can't do `_controller.InitialiseController();` Show some usage example.

Comment: Is correct that you derived `ComController` from `AIController` and not from `Controller`.

Comment: What exactly are you passing your snake.initialise(...) method? Please supply some code.

Comment: "actually the same logic as parent": well, you can just avoid putting another definition of `InitialiseController` in `ComController`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your thoughts, I've added a bit more code above. and used std::cout in both the Controller implementation and the ComController implementation.. definitely still running the Controller version.. @KristianDuske

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see anything wrong with what you're doing (at least as far as understanding and using virtual methods).

Here's a complete example.  Please compare it with your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Controller{
public:
    virtual void InitialiseController(){
      printf ("base class controller...\n");
    }
};

class AIController : public Controller{
public:
    virtual void InitialiseController(){
      printf ("AIController subclass controller...\n");
    }
};

class ComController : public AIController{
public:
    virtual void InitialiseController(){
      printf ("ComController subclass controller...\n");
    }
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Controller *myController = new ComController ();
   myController->InitialiseController ();
   return 0;
}
```

Compile:
`g++ -Wall -pedantic -o tmp tmp.cpp`

Execute:
`ComController subclass controller...`

Comment: AH! Would the problem be that i've just realised, ComControllers implementaion is private?? yes i thinkthat would be it! Thanks for taking the time to reiterate how this should work

Comment: Scratch that! i moved it to public and its still using the parent Controller implementation :(

Comment: I actually realised it was a spelling mistake.. Controller and the function call both had a missing 'i' whereas the other implementations where spelt correctly =_= sorry for wasting your time folks. Accepting this as the answer for it's clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're calling the virtual method on the object directly. Polymorphism kicks in only if you call via a pointer or reference.

Edit: You write both `_controller.InitialiseController();` and `_controller->InitialiseController();` (was that there before?), so I'm not entirely sure what you're doing.