# Misunderstanding Polymorphism C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have four classes, Bank, Account, Saving, and Checking. Both Saving and Checking are publicly inherited from Account. I have two virtual void functions in Account; deposit and withdraw. I'm only posting the code for the Saving deposit function because the problem is repeitive for the rest of the code.

I have a function in my Bank class that will add an account to a vector of type account. Whenever I call the deposit function for a savings object, it uses  the deposit function of Account and not Saving (found using debugger).

At first I was not using pointers, but I went through this thread: [Polymorphism misunderstanding / redefined virtual function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339612/polymorphism-misunderstanding-redefined-virtual-function-not-working) and learned to use pointers for virtual functions.

**QUESTION:** What is causing my code to use the default virtual method in Account.cpp instead of the intended "polymorphic" method in Saving.cpp? How can I fix it?

Account.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using std::string;
enum account_type { saving, checking };

class Account
{
public:
    Account();
    Account(int, account_type, double);
    ~Account();

    virtual void deposit(double&) {};
    virtual void withdraw(double&) {};
protected:
    int account_number;
    account_type type;
    double balance;

    int generateAccountNumber();
    double initializeBalance();
};
```

Saving.cpp

```
class Saving : public Account
{
public:
    Saving();
    Saving(int, account_type, double);
    ~Saving();

    void deposit(double&) //deposits some amount into a saving account
    {
        if (amount < 0)
            throw "Cannot withdraw an amount less than $0.00";
        else if (amount > balance)
            throw "Cannot withdraw an amount greater than the current balance";
        else
            balance -= amount;
    }
 private:
    const double interest_rate = 0.01;
};
```

Bank.cpp

```
class Bank
{
private:
    vector <Account*> bank_accounts;
    //ORIGINAL BEFORE FIX: vector <Account> bank_accounts;
public:
    void Bank::addAccount(Account a) //adds some account to a vector
    {
        bank_accounts.push_back(a);
    }

    Account * findAccount(int acc_num) //finds the account by it's account number
    { 
        int found = -1;
        for (int y = 1; y <= (int)bank_accounts.size(); y++) {
        if (acc_num == bank_accounts[y - 1].getAccountNumber())
            found = y - 1;
        }

         if (found == -1) {
             throw "\nAccount not found";
         }
        else
        {
            if (bank_accounts[found].getAccountType() == 0)
            {
                Account * saving = &bank_accounts[found];
                return saving;
            }
        else if (bank_accounts[found].getAccountType() == 1)
        {
                Account * checking = &bank_accounts[found];
                return checking;
        }
     }
  }
}

int main()
{
    Bank Swiss;
    Saving s(num, type, bal); // some user values for these variables
    Account * tempAccount1 = &s;
    Swiss.addAccount(*tempAccount1);
    Swiss.findAccount(num)->deposit(amt);
}
```

Comment: I must have missed it... I never saw an actual question anywhere...

Comment: I hazarded a look and must have missed it as well. 
@Raj, What, specifically is your question?

Comment: Because you're passing Account by value in Bank::addAccount, the variable named a will be "sliced" (treated as an Account instead of a Saving object). I don't know if that's the question.

Comment: You can detect these kinds of errors at compile time by making the functions pure virtual.

Comment: You're still not using pointers.

Comment: Please provide a question, otherwise nobody knows whats your intention is.

Comment: I updated the thread with a proper question since the original information was not clear enough for some people. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see the code that does this, but the question says that `Bank` has a **vector of account**, i.e., `std::vector<account>`. If that's the case, the problem is that derived-class objects get sliced into `account` objects when they are pushed into the vector, and they lose their derived-ness. The code needs to use pointers or references to `account`. Typically this is done with `std::vector<account*>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<account>>` and derived objects allocated with `new`. The code also should pass objects of types derived from `account` by pointers or references, and not by value (e.g., `void Bank::addAccount(Account a)` won't work because it will slice the argument that it's called with).

Comment: Might want to change `unique_ptr` to `std::unique_ptr` just to avoid any ambiguity

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury - done. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, these two lines in your code copy-construct `a` into an `Account` object, destroying the polymophic relationship.

```
    void Bank::addAccount(Account a) //adds some account to a vector
```

and

```
    bank_accounts.push_back(a);
```

I would suggest making `bank_accounts` and array of smart pointers to `Account*`. Also `addAccount` should be a reference (`Account&`) or a smart pointer.